# How to reduce android activity and app size?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, proguard, reduce

I'm new at android devolpment, so I am developing an alphabet app for an old language, the app would look like this

first page has a picture and two buttons

first button links to a page with text

second button links to a page with 24 images (alphabets), if you click on one of the image (alphabet) then you move on to a page with picture (alphabet) and below the picture there is a button to listen to the pronunciation of the letter

[image]

in the end the app will contain **50** *images*, **24** *audio* files and at least **30** *activity*

and the app size will be too large

**The question is can I use something else instead of activity?** or should I use use activity then reduce the app size? **ProGuard**??

I am developing at android **API 21** and the min Api is **API 8**

Comment: How do you know it will be too large? What *is* "too large"? You certainly can (and probably should) reuse the letter-associated activity instead of having one per letter, but I suspect that will barely matter in terms of application size. The bulk of the space will be taken up with the images and audio. The encoding of these will be key in reducing your overall file size.

Comment: @kabuko how do i know? let's say 100 kb per img 50= 5000 kb and the same for audio files, "too large" I mean when you compare with other apps in the market

Comment: For an app that includes multimedia, an extra 5MB doesn't sound that bad to me, but to a certain extent, you just have to decide for yourself. If people see value in your app, they'll download it even with an extra 5-10MB no problem. That said, 100KB/image sounds like a lot. Remember that you're on a mobile device, so I doubt you'll need anything more than 1920x1080. If you use something like JPG and use reasonable quality settings, I doubt it'd take 100KB per image. Audio is tougher, but ogg or mp3 at a low bitrate should be fine as it sounds like it's just voice and not high fidelity music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data into activities and fragments in Android, there is no need to create multiple activities that have a similar function.

If you decide to use an Activity you can pass data via an `Intent` which can contain extras, e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image_id", R.drawable.some_letter);
intent.putExtra("audio_file", "some_letter.mp3");
startActivity(intent);
```

Similarly, you can pass a `Bundle` of arguments to a fragment:

```
Fragment fragment = new NextFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("image_id", R.drawable.some_letter);
args.putString("audio_file", "some_letter.mp3");
fragment.setArguments(args);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the size, it sounds like you would greatly benefit from using fragments in your architecture.
[Android Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

If 50 images and 24 audio files add up to too much, you might want to check the resolution of the images and/or the compression of your audio files. How much is too much?