# individual activities include API call can I use fragment to reduce the activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

In my App for Tablet! welcome activity, login activity, registration activity, password activity, starter activity with viewPager, 
Message to send activity, scanning activity,
fill in form details activity, payment activity its about 25 activities with 25 layouts, 30 XML in Drawable for components background
and few images,fonts as of now

My Question is Since these individual activities include API call can I use fragment to reduce the activity, just because now 
my app is 3.31 MB it further may increase and by reducing activity increases performance of my app, So which is best Fragment or Activity? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using fragments certainly helps since they make your code very modular and reusable. If you have multiple parts of the screen that are similar in nature, you can simply use fragments to create them. In terms of the api calls and the business logic, you could consider using `MVVM` architecture for your app. That way you can have a common `ViewModel` for fragments that make similar api calls and in doing so you make the business logic somewhat reusable too. Some resources that you might find useful for MVVM:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Previous Stackoverflow post about fragments and app size:
[How to reduce android activity and app size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746967/how-to-reduce-android-activity-and-app-size)

It does sound like using fragments would be the way to go for your app too as opposed to using **25+ activities**.